# Evitar que se refresque plantilla al cambiar vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy haciendo una plantilla llamada "MasterPage", en donde pondre el menu de toda mi pagina y que cambia su clase al darle click, para poder distinguir la vista en la que nos encontramos.

```js
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
    $('li a.activo').removeClass('activo');
    $(this).addClass('activo');
});
```

```css
.activo {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a class="activo" href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#menu1">Iventario</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

La cosa es al dirigirnos al enlace, como retuna una vista toda la pagina se refresca y se pierde la clase "activo" nuevamente que agregue.

¿Como le hago para cargue solo la vista contenido?

```
@extends('MasterPage')
@section('contenido')
<div>....</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haría con [TurboLinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks)

Aquí dice cómo usarlo con Laravel:  https://medium.com/web-developer/turbolinks-with-laravel-speed-up-navigation-in-your-laravel-app-with-turobolinks-41efbade643b

Comment: Turbolinks permite mantener parte de a la vista estática entre cambios de vistas.  Es decir que refresca sólo parte de la vista como lo haría una Single Page Application, pero sin preocuparnos por usar Ajax.